# Text Field that appears if user choose Yes in the combo box in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add a text field and input text if the user choose "Yes" in the combo box; other wise nothing will be added. Tried this but didn't work

```
  Combo = ttk.Combobox(window, values = vlist)
  Combo.set("Pick an Option")
  Combo.pack()
  if (Combo.get()=="Yes"):
    tkinter.Label(window,  text="Number of Workers", bg = "white",fg = "black", font=("Times",13,"bold")).place(x=155,y=240)    
    inputtxt3 = Text(window, height = 1, width = 25, bg = "light yellow")
    inputtxt3.pack()
    inputtxt3.place(x=325, y=238)
```

Comment: Can you tell what is ```vlist```? Also, you need to set a ```StringVar``` for the combobox. Refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Label, Combobox, Button

root = Tk()

def check():    # For checking the value of ComboBox
    combo_value = var.get()
    if combo_value == "Yes":
        lbl.config(text="You selected 'Yes'")
    else:
        lbl.config(text="You selected 'No'")

var = StringVar()    # To store the value of the Combobox
Combo = Combobox(root, values=["Yes", "No"], textvariable=var)
Combo.pack(pady=20)

btn = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=check)
btn.pack(pady=20)

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks ! but is there a way to connect combo box selection action directly with appearing of the label without button?

Comment: Add `root.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: check())` before `root.mainloop()`. This will create a binding that is triggered every time an item is selected in the combobox and will call `check`.

Comment: Thanks !, I have 2 combo boxes but it worked only for the second combo box , I have 2 functions check() and checkRun() where check is related to combo1 and checkRun() related to combo2 , any suggestions for this issue?

Comment: worked, just did Combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: check()) 
Combo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda event: checkRun())

Thanks a lot for help!